# Qlogic QLE8152 connect to a DS14 disk shelf

Tags: linux, ethernet, netapp, fibre-channel, qlogic

I am trying to configure a NETAPP DS14 disk shelf to expose the drives to a windows or a linux machine, I don't have a controller but I got a FC to ethernet adapter (Qlogic 8152)

however the loop does not connect, I see that the DS14 supports max of 2gbps, however the adapter is listed as a 10gbps one, any ideas how to configure it to a lower speed?

I tried setting it via ethtool

```
sudo ethtool -s [device_name] speed [10/100/1000]
```

but I get an operation not supported error, does that mean i cannot switch to a lower speed? Or is there a different way to force the adapter to use a lower speed.

Comment: You need an actual FC HBA, not an FCoE HBA.

Comment: Do you have any specific model in mind that i can search for

Comment: Any FC HBA that supports 2Gbps or higher will do. You can find lots of them on eBay and similar sites and they will generally be very cheap (in part because they are so old). Expect to spend €25 or so including postage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Qlogic 8152 is an Ethernet NIC that can talk *Fibre Channel over Ethernet* but not native *Fibre Channel*. Fibre Channel uses different L1 and L2 protocols from Ethernet.

FCoE encapsulates FC frames in Ethernet frames and isn't understood by normal FC devices. FCoE is normally used to bridge FC networks over an intermediate Ethernet network.

You'll need a Fibre Channel HBA/initiator card ("controller") - for 2GFC these are quite inexpensive used. Alternatively, you'll need a translator bridge, likely much more expensive.